# О грамматике и правописании выражения "как бы не так"

Tags: орфография, грамматика, фразеология

**Из словаря Ефремовой:**

**как бы не та́к,** межд. разг.-сниж.
Возглас, выражающий категорическое несогласие или отказ от чего-либо.

Пример:.

А он, бестия, меня уверяет, что нечем; денег, дескать, нету… **Да, как бы не так**!.. На другой день мы тотчас после чаю опять отправились на охоту. [И. С. Тургенев. Хорь и Калиныч (1847)]

**И вопросы:**

1) **Каково происхождение** этого выражения (исходная грамматика)?

2) Как объяснить выбор **частицы НЕ**? Почему это именно отрицание?

3) Это разговорное или просторечное выражение? Как определить **стиль** и область применения?

Answer (score 3):

```
  Каково происхождение этого 
   выражения (исходная грамматика)?
```

Не знаю, насколько корректен этот вопрос... Междометия в виде коммуникем  (коммуникативов) по структуре являются нерасчленёнными предложениями. Их значение  может образовываться на разных основаниях. В одном случае оно складывается из номинативных значений слов. В другом  связано с психоэмоциональной сферой деятельности человека, которую они и призваны обслуживать. Такие построения выражают обобщенное значение (“утверждение”/”отрицание”, “положительной”/“негативной” оценки и т.п.), делают это нерасчленённо, без строгой дифференциации, без опоры на номинативное значение языковых единиц, входящих в них. ***Как бы не так*** как раз к ним и относится.

Грамматика-80 квалифицирует коммуникативы  в разделе “Морфология” в качестве частиц и междометий, способных выступать в роли “реплик” (или “эквивалентов предложения”) различного характера: утвердительных, отрицательных, эмоциональных и т.п.

Можно,конечно, пофантазировать и восстановить отрезок речи, который замещает междометное предложение, ведь нерасчленённость коммуникатива тем и объясняется, что основной их функцией является выражение большего содержания меньшими средствами. Эти малые средства не всегда позволяют чётко разграничить и выделить все компоненты замещаемого  отрезка, н-р: 1) Как бы не так!Как раз! (“отрицание + негодование, возмущение, ирония...”) вместо: Как вам не стыдно! Я не согласен с вашим мнением! Это безнравственно! и т.д.

Можно восстановить и предполагаемую исходную конструкцию по структурным компонентам:

**как бы** - условно-предположительное сравнение;

**как бы не так** - так ни в каком случае не будет.

Возможно, исходная конструкция: ***Как бы*** вы ни хотели (ни предполагали), но **так** ни в каком случае **не** будет!  Или ещё ближе и короче: ***Как бы вам ни хотелось, но это не так!***

```
   Как объяснить выбор частицы НЕ? Почему это именно 
  отрицание?
```

Это по смыслу категорическое отрицание, потому и **НЕ**. Это реплика-утверждение, что это **НЕ ТАК**.

```
   Это разговорное или просторечное выражение? 
   Как определить стиль и область применения?
```

Несмотря на то, что в Словаре эмоционально-экспрессивных оборотов живой речи В.Ю. Меликяна коммуникатив ***как бы не так*** фиксируется с пометой «просторечное», приходится констатировать, что **сегодня он переходит в разряд разговорных, судя по его употреблению в публицистике при несогласии-опровержении**. Вот некоторые примеры:

*Игра сделана? Как бы не так! Страсти зашкаливают, и вот уже, «сталевары» остаются втроем.* («Советский спорт», 2011.02.25) *Вы думаете, что наученные горьким опытом россияне не будут участвовать в этой авантюре? Как бы не так! Уже четыре тысячи человек принесли свои денежки.* («Комсомольская правда», 2011.02.01)

*Наконец его прогоняют и ставят ноль. Выдумаете: теперь он, по крайней мере, уйдёт! Как бы не так! Он возвращается на своё место, так же неподвижно сидит до конца экзамена*. (Тургенев. Гамлет Щигровского уезда). 
 https://phraseology.academic.ru/5135

Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона даёт толкование фразы без пометы **прост.**

Видимо, область применения междометия в наше время не ограничивается разговорным стилем бытового общения и  речевой характеристикой героев в языке художественных произведений, его ирония - частый приём и в публицистике в авторской речи, где экспрессия вполне на месте.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 1) По поводу корректности вопроса. Фразеологизм записали в междометия, но могли бы этого и не делать. "Эмоциональная" группа междометий, по определению, выражает чувства, но не называет их. А слово "нет" вообще относят к модальным частицам (или куда его сейчас относят)? Но и междометия бывают производные и непроизводные, и вот производные междометия в генетическом плане соотносятся с исходными  словами и словосочетаниями. А меня как раз генетика интересовала.

Comment: 2) О генетике. Как известно, даже для нерасчленимых в современном языке фразеологизмов можно (и очень желательно) реконструировать  исходную грамматику. Люди же не произвольный набор слов произносят, а вполне связанное по смыслу выражение, которое надо просто расшифровать, но отнюдь не фантазировать на эту тему. Я попытаюсь предложить свой вариант в ответе, но это тоже в качестве одной из версий.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ будет коротким, я просто озвучу собственную версию происхождения фразеологизма.

Я думаю,что это первая часть такого выражения: "**Как бы получилось не так, как ты думаешь, а по-другому.**  Если совсем коротко: **как бы не так**.

В этом случае это синтаксическая конструкция **с противопоставлением,** поэтому здесь пишется  отрицательная частица НЕ.

Comment: Но тогда это будет предположение, ирреальная модальность, а на самом деле здесь явное категорическое отрицание, что закреплено во всех словарях. Первая часть - от восстановленного придаточного (как бы ни...), а вторая - отрицание не так.

Comment: Сначала была "ирреальная модальность" (я же говорю о генетике), а в современном значение стало категорическим отрицанием.

Comment: Нигде не видела такой истории с изменением значения, веде указано на категорическое отрицание. У Вас есть такой материал?

Comment: Я тоже не видела никакой истории, где бы рассказывалось о происхождении этого  фразеологического сочетания.  Но история, безусловно, существует, так как при изучении фразеологизмов указывается  не только их значение, но и происхождение. Поэтому я и задала такой вопрос, надеясь, что кто-нибудь поможет мне найти этот материал. А пока его нет, я привожу собственную версию, причем в ответе это указано

Comment: А я Вам привела мнение профессора, что "такие коммуникативы  выражают обобщенное значение (“утверждение”/”отрицание”,положительной”/“негативной” оценки и т.п.), делают это нерасчленённо, без опоры на номинативное значение языковых единиц, входящих в них. Как бы не так как раз к ним и относится". Так что определённого материала нет. Вы одно нафантазировали, я другое, каждый остался при своём мнении, только Вы почему-то заменили категорическое отрицание, о котором говорится во всех словарях, на предположение.

Comment: Профессор говорит о значении и восприятии междометий в современном языке, но не о происхождении их.  Нельзя объяснить только непроизводные междометия (ах, ой),  но это не наш случай. Генетику неразложимых сочетаний изучает этимология. Эти сочетания вовсе не бессмысленный набор слов.

Comment: Ну я так думаю, а пока источника нет,  можно что-то предположить самому, а для этого надо просто вслушаться в эту фразу. Я думаю, что это полезное упражнение для всех пользователей, любящих и чувствующих язык, в том числе и для школьников. Не обязательно сразу раскрывать перед ними все секреты, пусть предложат свои версии. Человека надо учить мыслить, а не только наполнять иеющимися знаниями